# custom sort for a mongodb collection in meteor

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have this collection of products and i want to display a `top 10 products` based on a custom sort function

```
[{ _id: 1, title, tags:['a'], createdAt:ISODate("2016-01-28T00:00:00Z") } ,
{ _id: 2, title, tags:['d','a','e'], createdAt:ISODate("2016-01-24T00:00:00Z") }]
```

What i want to do is to sort it based on a "magic score" that can be calculated. For example, based on this formula: `tag_count*5 - number_of_days_since_it_was_created`.

If the first one is 1 day old, this makes the score:

```
[{_id:1 , score: 4}, {_id:2, score: 10}]
```

I have a few ideas on how i can achieve this, but i'm not sure how good they are, especially since i'm new to both mongo and meteor:

1. start an observer (Meteor.observe) and every time a document is
   modified (or a new one created), recalculate the score and update it
   on the collection itself. If i do this, i could just use $orderBy
   where i need it.
2. after some reading i discovered that mongo aggregate or map_reduce
   could help me achieve the same result, but as far as i found out,
   meteor doesn't support it directly
3. sort the collection on the client side as an array, but using this
   method i'm not sure how it will behave with pagination (considering that i subscribe to a limited number of documents)

Thank you for any information you can share with me!

Comment: The only way to do this at runtime is to implement an aggregate statement, since you cannot provide a function to sort server side in any other way ( note that mapReduce does not sort results with the exception of keys to reduce are sorted, but also not suitable for paging on a calculated field ). An alternate approach given your requirement is to store the field and simply recalculate it daily ( and likely also on update ). That's a simple scheduled task and then a basic sort on the already present field. Also more performant that way.

Comment: So instead of adding an event listener for each product update, i should rather just run a cron once in a while? To be honest, it does make sense, especially since i don't need the score to be real-time. As for how to do this, should i use a `cursor.each()` or is there any better alternative? I haven't figured out if i can do something like this in mongodb: `"UPDATE products SET score = tags_count * 10"`, where i set a field based on the value of others. Thanks @BlakesSeven

Comment: That was the idea. Your requirement states "days old", so that doesn't sound like it needs real time. Storing pre-calculated seems definately the way to go here.

Comment: or you can write a custom publish function, where you can do pretty much whatever you want to. You can follow the "counts-by-room" example from the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish.

Comment: I tried that approach as well, but you can't pretty much do whatever you want to. For example, i couldn't find a way i could use this method with $limit (so i don't publish all the documents).  All i could achieve was to publish a "score" on the client along with all the documents ` added: function(id, fields) { fields.score = fields.tags.length* 15; self.added("products", id, fields); }`

Comment: Perhaps the package [maximum:computed-fields](https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/computed-fields) would allow you to compute the score reactively server-side. Then you can use the classic `{sort:{score:1}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literal function sorting [is just being implemented in meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2730), so you should be able to do something like

```
Products.find({}, {sort: scoreComparator});
```

**in an upcoming release**.

You can use the [transform property when creating collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection). In this transform, store the magic operation as a function.

```
score=function(){
    // return some score
};
transformer=function(product){
  product.score=score; 
  // one could also use prototypal inheritance 
};
Products=new Meteor.Collection('products',{transform:transformer});
```

Unfortunately, [you cannot yet use the sort operator on virtual fields](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1852), because minimongo does not support it.

So the ultimate fall-back as you mentioned while nor the virtual field sorting nor the literate function sorting are supported in minimongo is client side sorting :

```
// Later, within some template 
scoreComparator=function(prd1,prd2){
  return prd1.score()-prd2.score(); 
}
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  products:function(){
    return Products.find().fetch().sort(scoreComparator);
  }
});
```

> i'm not sure how it will behave with pagination (considering that i subscribe to a limited number of documents)

**EDIT** : the score will be computed among the subscribed documents, indeed.